# Use one classifier for multiple sets of features

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

I have recently started learning machine learning using scikit-learn and I have a question regarding using one classifier for multiple feature sets.  For my example, I'm using the RandomForestClassifier for different sets of features.  I'm using Python 3.4.3 and here's my code:

```
    forest = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 10, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators = 100, random_state = 1)

    forest_1 = forest.fit(X_1, y)
    forest_2 = forest.fit(X_2, y)
    forest_3 = forest.fit(X_3, y)

    print(forest_1.score(X_1, y))
    print(forest_2.score(X_2, y))
    print(forest_3.score(X_3, y))
```

The above code gave me an error, stated as "Number of features of the model must  match the input. Model n_features is 7 and  input n_features is 4". The number of features for my X_1 is 4, and X_2 is 7, so I changed my code to the following:

```
    forest_1 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 10, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators = 100, random_state = 1)
    forest_2 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 10, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators = 100, random_state = 1)
    forest_3 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 10, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators = 100, random_state = 1)

    forest_1 = forest_1.fit(X_1, y)
    forest_2 = forest_2.fit(X_2, y)
    forest_3 = forest_3.fit(X_3, y)

    print(forest_1.score(X_1, y))
    print(forest_2.score(X_2, y))
    print(forest_3.score(X_3, y))
```

This works fine, but it seems redundant to me that I have to create 3 separate classifiers when all of the properties are the same.  Is there a better way of doing this, or I just have to stick to creating different classifiers for different feature sets?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? As you observed, most classifiers need a fixed feature-dimension, so you got two basic possibilities: A) Combine the features into one dataset (X = np.hstack((X_1, X_2, X_3)); assuming y is the same for all and the number of samples is the same for each X_i; the features are concatenated) B) Learning multiple classifiers and combine the output. It depends on the data and the combination of the output which is better suited here.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I apologize that I was not clear in my original post.  What I was trying to do is to compare the results using different number of features, so many features are the same between X_1, X_2, and X_3 (e.g. X_2 includes X_1 and more other features).  The problem I encountered earlier is that the variable "forest" cannot be reused, which I am not sure why that's the reason.  It seems like the purpose of "forest" is just to identify the classifier I'm using, and not used to store any information.  Now I have bypassed this problem by defining a function in my script.